# Give a top inset to UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uirefreshcontrol

I use an UIRefreshControl like it (without an UITableViewController) :

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(viewDidBeginRefreshing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.table addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Problem is the refresh wheel is positioned below the UINavigationController's translucent bar (ios7).
There is only a few topic on this problem on StackOverflow. And they didn't bring any valuable solution to me.

What I wish is to make my UIRefreshControl's y position 80px down for example.

**Note :** I know it's not recommended to use UIRefreshControl outside an UITableViewController. So no need to warn about it.

Comment: Can be good to note that my UITableView is set up with auto-layout, as the rest of my views, programmatically. (But shouldn't have anything to do with it)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found a solution, very simple, not so clean but works like a charm.

Just need to put the refresh control in another subview which is set down.

```
UIView *refreshView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 0, 0)];
[self.table addSubview:refreshView];

UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(viewDidBeginRefreshing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[refreshView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Comment: As shown above make sure to add the container `UIView` to the `UITableView` before you add the `UIRefreshControl` as a subview to the container `UIView`. I had done it vice-versa and it fails.

Comment: `'UIRefreshControl may only be managed by a UITableViewController'`, I think caused by the issue @pechar notes

Comment: is there something the same for UICollectionView?

Answer (score 2):

This is a version of AncAinu's answer in Swift 4.

```
let refreshView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: 0, height: 0))
tableView.addSubview(refreshView)

refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()        
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.viewDidBeginRefreshing), for: .valueChanged)        
refreshView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the viewDidLoad in your `UIViewController`:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: It works but... not the way I want, it makes the navigation bar opaque and constraint down the whole table.