# Swift: Shift refreshControl down

Tags: swift, uikit

How do I move the refreshControl down further? I did it in code:

[image]

```
lazy var refresh: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refresh = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 20, height: 20))
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fetchMatches), for: .valueChanged)
        return refresh
    }()

tableView.addSubview(refresh)
```

Note that this is not UITableViewController, but UIViewController with tableView dragged in just 8 pts below the segmentedController.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499182/give-a-top-inset-to-uirefreshcontrol

Comment: See this guide here: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/ More specifically, navigate to **Custom Refresh Contents.**